# How to check if the object returned is Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a declaration..

```
var cabResults = Dictionary<CabType, [CabResult]>()
```

Now I want to check if the object is present in the dictionary for a particular key.. which can be don by

```
if self.cabResults[currentCabType] != nil
```

Now I also want to check if the object returned by  `self.cabResults[currentCabType]` is of type `[CabResult]`

How can I get this..?

Comment: `if varName is Array<CabResult>{...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `if let ... as? ...`:

```
if let cabs = self.cabResults[currentCabType] as? [CabResult] {
    // yep
} else {
    // nope
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check is the object is will and do another check is that of any particular type, you can just do:

```
if let myObject = self.cabResults[currentCabType] as? [CabResult] {
    // myObject is not till and is of type myObject
} else {
    // the object is nil or it's not of type myObject
}
```